# How to get deleted text in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, drag, backspace

I want to get deleted text in `UITextView`.

Because I have to decrease `UITextView`, when '\n' deleted.

However, `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate method is only return last string.

So, For example

```
UITextView.text = @"ABCD\nEFG";
```

and user delete text is `@"D\nEFG"`.

Then, returned text is not '\n'. so I do not know whether the line number should be reduced. help me!

Comment: you can check Text Size. so when Text Size decrease then decrease UITextView .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the range of text that is going to be changed within `shouldChangeTextInRange`.

Before you return `YES` from `shouldChangeTextInRange`, you can scan the characters within that range to see if there is a "`\n`" or "`\r`" character there and then you can decrease the line number by the number of new line characters found in the range.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Solution

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

> With this following code, you can change the height of your UITextView
>    depending of a fixed width (it's working on iOS 7 and previous version) :

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

**With this function, you will take a NSAttributedString and a fixed width to return the height needed.
If you want to calculate the frame from a text with a specific font you, need to use the following code :**

```
- (CGSize)text:(NSString *)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])‌
    {
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                          context:nil];
        return frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        return [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    }
}
```

> This worked for me for iOS6 and 7:

```
CGSize textViewSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    self.myTextView.height = textViewSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the height of UItextView -

```
CGSize textViewSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"font_name" size:font_size] 
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(WIDHT_OF_VIEW, FLT_MAX) 
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

Replace font_name and font_size with actual value that you are using in UITextView.
and Replace WIDHT_OF_VIEW with width of your UITextView.

You can get the height of UITextView using below code-
textViewSize.height